# How you add the greyed out parameter hints (msg, context) for methods in Android Studio for Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

On the image underlined is written grayed out the "msg" word. Had looked around but can't tell how you make it appear like that.

Can't copy paste the code because that word is not being copied.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Jetbrains' help article on inline parameter name hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Inline_Parameter_Name_Hints.html), it covers both the reasoning behind the feature as well as configuration options.

Comment: Thank you for the info. So you don't add them they are being added automatically, thanks a lot